# Adding and activating firefox addons in GeckoFX

Tags: c#, firefox, geckofx, xpi

I need to add and activate a spell checker plugin (es-ES@....xpi) in GeckoFx, in a C# program. I've been reading some answers here and some other forums, but none of them have worked. Anyone has managed to get an xpi Firefox addon working in GeckoFX? Thanks